# Weighted matching and spanning set in $2$-polymatroids

Tags: co.combinatorics, matroid-theory

A **$2$-polymatroid** $P$ is a pair $(S, f)$, where $S$ is a finite set and $f: 2^{S} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ is a function satisfying the following:

- $f(\varnothing) = 0$;
- $f(X) \leq f(Y)$, for any $X \subseteq Y$;
- $f(X \cup Y) + f(X \cap Y) \leq f(X) + f(Y)$, for any $X, Y \subseteq S$;
- $f(\{x\}) \leq 2$, for any $x \in S$.

A subset $X \subseteq S$ is a **matching** of $P$ if $f(X) = 2|X|$ and it is a **spanning set** of $P$ if $f(X) = f(S)$.

Generalizing Gallai's identity, Lovasz showed that $\nu(P) + \rho(P) = f(S)$, where $\nu(P)$ (resp. $\rho(P)$) denotes the size of a maximum matching (resp. minimum spanning set) of $P$ (see, for example, Lovasz and Plummer book). This implies that finding a maximum matching is polynomially equivalent to finding a minimum spanning set.

Is it known whether the weighted versions of the problems are equivalent?

Comment: please define weighted versions.